# How to get address of contract from inside the contract?

Tags: contract-design, addresses

```
contract FooContract{

    address myAddress = ??
}
```

How to get the address of a contract from inside (the contract itself)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`this` is the address of the contract:

```
class FooContract {

   function myAddress() constant returns(address) {
      return this;
   }
}
```